# PHP openssl_pkcs7_verify returns true on invalid certificate

Tags: php, openssl, smime

I'm trying to verify S/MIME message signature using openssl_pkcs7_verify().

With 'transport testing tool' http://transport-testing.nist.gov/ttt/
I'm sending sample S/MIME messages to my address and after succesfull decoding, I try to verify it's signature.

When the certificate is correct, I get success,
but I also get success when certificate is invalid.

How can I verify it correctly with PHP or openssl command?

```
<?php
# Good cert
$bRes = openssl_pkcs7_verify('decoded_1.txt', 0, 0, array('nist.gov.pem', 'sampleca.nist.gov.pem'));
$bErr = openssl_error_string();
var_dump($bRes, $bErr); # returns true, false

# Invalid cert
$bRes = openssl_pkcs7_verify('decoded_2.txt', 0, 0, array('nist.gov.pem', 'sampleca.nist.gov.pem'));
$bErr = openssl_error_string();
var_dump($bRes, $bErr); # returns true, false
```

[Source files](http://pasted.co/b0d19318)

Notice that CCDA_Inpatient.xml in thers files are the same, but smime.p7s differs.

Comment: I have managed to run openssl command on my data.
At first I merged 2 certificates into 1 file:
  "cat sampleca.nist.gov.pem nist.gov.pem > concat.pem"

Then I run "openssl smime -verify -in decoded_1.txt -CAfile concat.pem" and get result = 0. The same result with decoded_2.txt. Weird...